# Windows 10 lowers microphone volume after 1 second of sound length

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I tried to record some music with my laptop microphone and external microphones, but aside that these are different, the effect is the same (external ones work good on my stationary PC);

What I mean that it lowers input strength after 1 second. If I play single, stable sound that should not change in volume (organs), the input results in something like this:

[image]

It always happens at the same time of sound length, about in a second.

I use OBS and windows built-in Voice Recorder. There are no programs that would change microphone strength, because it happens also in Microphone Listening mode. I disabled changing microphone volume in settings anyway. What could be cause of this? I'll provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for the record, here's how I solved it:

I went to Manage Audio Device (just typed sound in windows startup menu) > Recording tab > Right click on microphone > properties > Enhancement tab > check the box "Disable all sound effects".

This seems to work in the long run for me, good luck for the others.

Answer (score -1):

The enhancement suggestion for me did not work.

It happens with my HyperX Cloud II headset but not with any of my other microphones. I am connected via USB on PC and directly into the mic/headset port on a Mac. The issue still occurs on the Mac. That makes me think that it's something wrong with the headset itself and not caused by Windows 10.

You can see in this Audacity screenshot that when I record a continuous tone, it drops after about 1 second.

Microphone level lowering after 1 second of continuous input:
[image: microphone level lowering after 1 second of continuous input]